# What do you call a class that you're extending/inheriting from?

Tags: oop

I'm having a technical interview tomorrow and I wanna make sure I'm using the right terms.

Would you call it a parent class, a class you're inheriting from?

Comment: ancestor class, parent class, base class are the usual ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parent class or base class, it doesn't matter which term you use, any developer worth their salt would understand it.